# Change background of a uinavigation right button?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am successful in changing the text of the **right navigation button** by given code. But i also want to change it has a **delfault background** .

I simply want to show a text with transparent background.

I have also tried

```
 UIBarButtonItem *rightBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(myMethod)];

rightBtn.tintColor =[UIColor clearColor];
```

but still showing a button background.

Is there a way to achieve it by changing any different style which don't have background. or is there an other simple way to change button to a text with no transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [btn setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];


    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBtn];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Can you show me the code you have in viewDidLoad:, including the creation of the UIBarButtonItem. (This has worked for me in a current project).